# Debug is showing this code to be looping forever but there's nothing that should allow that to happen

Tags: vba, excel

As the title says this code is creating a loop for some reason.

```
Sub Title()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim myCell As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 3), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))


Range("B:B").Style = "Normal"
Range("B1").Style = "Good"

For Each myCell In rng
    If myCell.Value = UCase(myCell.Value) Then
        myCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(myCell.Value)
    End If

    myCell.Value = " " & myCell.Value & " "

Next myCell

rng.Replace "  ", " "
```

For some reason it also adds spaces to thousands of lines below itself. I can't seem to figure this one out. Any Advice is much welcomed.

Comment: Well yes, the For is a loop. Do you mean that the loop never ends? Have you tried stepping through line by line? I think its likely to do with your `rng`. Can you place a break and see what address its populating with?

Comment: Are you calling it from an event handler? Is this all the code? I don't see any uses of `rng1`.

Comment: Agreed With Comintern - there is now way this is all of your code.

Comment: How big is the range, if it is big, that code will take fore ever to finish.

Comment: @nbayly I have gone step by step and it loops through the range indefinitely even with 4 rows worth of data.

Comment: @Comintern it's a work in progress. It's not option explicit yet because I'm yet to use rng1. however the only thing you're not seeing is screen updating and end sub.

Comment: @KyloRen I've gone step by step and it adds spaces correctly however for some reason it keeps looping down after the last filled cell. I've deleted the rows below it just to make sure and I still encounter this problem

Comment: For anyone interested it was the uppercase lowercase part in my for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this

```
If myCell.Value = UCase(myCell.Value) Then
         myCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(myCell.Value)
End If
```

is the source of the issue. Removing this solves the odd infinite loop.